# How to use IN operator in Oracle SQL when select statement itself in quotes

Tags: database, oracle

I want to introduce an IN clause within already created query which is in single quotes of oracle SQL function.

`Execute immediate 'Select last_name from table_name where first_name = ''John'''`

The above query is able to select last_name of an employee

now i want to use multiple names using IN operator under where clause. find below :

```
Execute immediate 'Select last_name from table_name where first_name IN(''John'',''Jack'')'
```

I know this is a wrong approach because its not working. So which is the best approach to resolve this problem ?

Comment: I don't understand this - does the code actually have a single-quote before the "Execute immediate ..."? Because, as it stands there is an imbalance of single quotes across the whole snippet. Normally I would expect EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to be outside quotes, and also in your case you would need a "INTO" clause to put the query results somewhere. Secondly the query looks likely to return > 1 row, so perhaps you are using the wrong construct/method entirely. Not enough detail to answer the question.

Comment: only the select statement is in quotes and yes, you're right INTO is attached to it which i have not described as i thought there is no need of it because its obvious as you have already explained.

Comment: The second query should work just fine (the first one is missing one `'` at the end) What exactly is the problem? What error message do you get?

Comment: actually I cant see database error because this currently 4-5 applications are bind together resulting in forming 1 service. so changing in database will impact another application built in java and there are so many things. so error is not appropriate. All I can see that if query is syntactically correct or not. If the line of code is not correct it is showing one small bar at the starting line, when query is correct that bar line is getting wiped off.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
Q_STRING := q'{Select last_name from table_name where first_name IN ('John','Jack')}';    
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE Q_STRING;
```

Also, why do you have a single quote before the word "Execute"?

Comment: my bad.. Only select statement is in singe quotes

Comment: `q'[]' ` will consider `'` as part of string , it wont eliminate it i guess. As already mention by a_horse_with_no_name the second query of Raman should work

Comment: Thanks @NagendraNigade, I forgot to change the paired single quotes into standard single quotes. It is fixed now.

Comment: I am thinking like `q'{'Select last_name from table_name where first_name IN ('John','Jack')'}';`. as Q_STRING is `varchar`